# What is the secret achievement in Ohh1?

Tags: achievements, 0h-h1

What is the secret achievement in the game? I've got all but that & Jennifer. I'm fairly certain that it can't be getting a score that ends with 42, so unless it's a "get everything" achievement, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Playing on my android device, the secret achievement is titled:

> "How Very Social of You."  You can find the name of the achievements on [Github](https://github.com/Q42/0hh1/blob/master/js/playcenter.js) looking through the code.

It's unlocked by:

> Pressing one of the social media buttons at the bottom of the screen when you are choosing what board to play.  I pressed the Twitter button and the achievement unlocked. However, the game did nothing.  This could be because I don't have twitter installed on my device. Pressing the Facebook button prompted me to share the game to Facebook.